# Can my front door swing away from the wall?

Tags: doors

Currently we have a 36" front door that we want to replace.  It has a faux door vintage late 60s USA on the outside.  So on the outside it looks like we have double doors but really just one door - so we need to cover a 72" gap that is surrounded by brick on each side.

The current dooris right handed and  is about 8 inches from wall that it hits when it is opened.  So it opens at about 110 degrees into a wall.

We are moving to a door + a sidelite/window setup on each side at 14"-18".

So window panel then door then window panel to cover the whole door space of 72".

Should the door still open to the wall or does it matter?  So if we go to a LH door it would open all the way to the wall the door is on - 180 degrees.  If we go RH door it will eventually hit current wall it is on (could put a bench there) but at a greater angle than it current does since it will be at least 12-16" further away - hinges to wall.

Comment: Perhaps a drawing would be helpful?

Comment: A dome  floor mount door stop may work if your threshold is not too high. 1 1/2" gap is about the biggest gap over the floor they accommodate without adding a block under them with is unsightly and weakens the mount. There are other styles of floor mounts, the dome is the strongest IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If I read it right, you have room for it to swing either way. No it does not need to swing to a wall.

Two things to consider for your door, does the swing help enter the room? In other words does it help the traffic flow? The other is were the light switch is for that space. Typically the light switch in on the latch side, not the hinge side.

Comment: That is a really good point about light switch (which is on wall) that I hadn't really thought about.   It would seem that I would have crossed this questions years ago but guess I have been lucky with entry doors.